# Retrieving Outlook 'Inbox' and 'Sent' folders in Delphi using OLE

Tags: delphi, com, outlook, ole

What's the best way to go about extracting Outlook folders from within Delphi? Ideally I'd like to retrieve the Inbox folder and any other folders within it. I don't require the email headers/message just purely the folder names.

Delphi BDS 2006

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa221870%28v=office.11%29.aspx) for Outlook's Object Model. Below displays the names of folders in the Inbox:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Outlook, oNameSpace, Inbox: OleVariant;
  i: Integer;
begin
  try
    Outlook := GetActiveOleObject('Outlook.Application');
  except
    Outlook := CreateOleObject('Outlook.Application');
  end;
  oNameSpace := Outlook.GetNamespace('MAPI');
  oNameSpace.Logon('', '', False, False);   // not sure if this is necessary
  Inbox := oNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox);
  for i := 1 to Inbox.Folders.Count do
    ShowMessage(Inbox.Folders[i].Name);
end;
```

Comment: `olFolderInbox` is `6` BTW, more in 'outlook2000.pas' or 'outlookxp.pas' in the `OCX\Servers` folder of RAD Studio installation. And 'comobj.pas' should be included in the 'uses' clause..

Comment: Or import the type library of Microsoft Outlook 16.0 object library.